# [HTML/JavaScript]: getElementByID not getting value

Tags: javascript, html

I am not able to figure out why it is not tracing value for CompanyType. If I remove the CompanyType block from verification, it works well. It even successfully verifies CompanyName, but it fails at CompanyType.

Below is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript>

//Check Company Name
if (document.getElementById("CompanyName").value == "")
{
     alert("Please enter company name");
     document.getElementById("CompanyName").focus();
     return false;                              
}

//Check Company Type                            alert(document.getElementById("CompanyType").value);
if (document.getElementById("CompanyType").value.substr(0,6) == "Select")
{
     alert("Please select company type");
     document.getElementById("CompanyType").focus();
     return false;                              
}
</Script>
```

Following lines follow in the HTML code in the file:

```
<td align="left" valign="top">
<input maxlength="40" size="22" name="CompanyName" id="CompanyName" style="width:150px;">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="38" colspan="2" valign="middle" id="form">
<span class="red">*</span>
<span class="style2">Company Type:</span>
</td>

<td align="left">
<select id=" " class="style3" size="1" name="CompanyType" style="width:150px;">                                                                      <option value="" selected="selected">Select One</option>                                                                               </select></td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing id attribute in CompanyType `select`

```
<select id=" " class="style3" size="1" name="CompanyType" style="width:150px;"> 
           ^^^
```

should be

```
<select id="CompanyType" class="style3" size="1" name="CompanyType" style="width:150px;">
```

And David Dorward has a point with regards to the order of the above.
HTML first, `<script>` after.

Best to execute JS when the document's ready though. Consider using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Comment: Then David Darward's answer is the solution for you. Make sure you call objects when they are created, not before.

Comment: @Michal: Thanks for the valuable tip. I am modifying accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to get the element before it exists. Most the script so it is after the HTML that it tries to access.

Comment: `getElementById("CompanyName")` is called before the element by id `CompanyName` is created.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the said by others about correct ID it is better access select values as follows:

```
var select = document.getElementById("CompanyType");

if (select[select.selectedIndex].value.substr(0,6) == "Select") {
    // something here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined an id for CompanyType, only a name.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is simple - you trying to get element by id "CompanyType", but your select element has empty id, add id="CompanyType" in your select element